# hi all, i'm having an error about the existence of a variable, can anyone help me out ? thanks

Tags: apex

here is my code:

```
public class AddPriceModalController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getRegionValues() {
        List<String> lstGeography = new List<String>(); //new list for holding all of the picklist options

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = PriceDetail__c.Geography__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        lstGeography.add(f.getValue());
    }

    return lstGeography;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getDeliveryMethodValues() {
    List<String> lstSourceOfSupply = new List<String>(); //new list for holding all of the picklist options

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = PriceDetail__c.Source_of_Supply__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        lstSourceOfSupply.add(f.getLabel() + '---' + f.getValue());            
    }

    return lstSourceOfSupply;
}
//Method to Save the Price Detail Change Request
@AuraEnabled
public static String savePriceDetails(Id PDID,PriceDetail__c newPriceDetails) {
    system.debug('savePriceDetails');
    system.debug('newPriceDetails'+newPriceDetails);
    Decimal invoiceCost = 0;
    Decimal netCost = 0;
    Decimal netProfit = 0;
    Decimal retailPrice = 0;
    string resultId;
    //Webservice Call to SAP to get the InvoiceCost and NetCost
    /*invoiceCost = PriceDetailsWebService.getInvoiceCost(PDID);
netCost = PriceDetailsWebService.getNetCost(PDID);*/

    String PDSOQL = SObjectUtil.getSOQLStringFullFields(PriceDetail__c.getSObjectType())
        +' WHERE ' + ' Id = :PDID LIMIT 1';
    //List<PriceDetail__c> listPD = Database.query(PDSOQL);
    PriceDetail__c PDRec;
    try{
        PDRec = Database.query(PDSOQL);   
    }catch(Exception e){
        ApplicationLogUtility.logError('SubmitActionController', 'getParentId', e, e.getMessage(), '', 0);
        ApplicationLogUtility.commitLog();
        PDRec = null; 
    }   
    if(PDRec!=null){
        PriceDetail__c clonedPD = PDRec.clone(false, true, false, false);
        clonedPD.InvoiceCost__c = invoiceCost;
        clonedPD.NetCost__c = netCost;
        clonedPD.ClonedFrom__c = PDRec.Id;
        clonedPD.Status__c = Label.Draft;
        clonedPD.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.PriceDetail__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(Label.PriceDetail_Submit).getRecordTypeId();
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = PriceDetail__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        for(string apiName : objResult.fields.getMap().keySet()){
            String feildName = apiName;
            if(feildName.endsWith('__c')){
                if((clonedPD.get(apiName) != newPriceDetails.get(apiName)) && (feildName!= 'ClonedFrom__c')){
                    system.debug('feildName***'+feildName);
                    clonedPD.put(apiName, newPriceDetails.get(apiName));
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug('clonedPD**'+clonedPD);
        if(clonedPD!=null){
            insert clonedPD;    
        }

        resultId = Id.valueOf(clonedPD.Id);
        system.debug('resultId'+resultId);

    }

    return resultId;
}

//Method to get the exsisting data from the record
@AuraEnabled
public static PriceDetail__c getPriceDetails(Id recordId) {
    system.debug('recordId**'+recordId);
    PriceDetail__c pdRecord = (PriceDetail__c) SObjectUtil.getFullSObject(PriceDetail__c.getSObjectType(), recordId);
    return pdRecord;

}

}
```

here is the test class:

```
@isTest
private class AddPriceModalControllerTest {

@testSetup 
static void createData() {
   PriceDetail__c pD = PDRec.clone(false, true, false, false);
        pD.InvoiceCost__c = 999;
        pD.NetCost__c = 577;
        pD.Status__c = Label.Draft;
        pD.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.PriceDetail__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(Label.PriceDetail_Submit).getRecordTypeId();
        insert pD;
}

@isTest static void getRegionValuesTest(){
    System.assertNotEquals(null, AddPriceModalController.getRegionValues());
}

@isTest static void getDeliveryMethodValuesTest(){
    System.assertNotEquals(null, AddPriceModalController.getDeliveryMethodValues());
}

@isTest static void savePriceDetailsTest(){
    List<PriceDetail__c> pD = [Select Id, InvoiceCost__c, NetCost__c, RecordTypeId  FROM PriceDetail__c];
    System.assertNotEquals(null, AddPriceModalController.savePriceDetails(pD[0].Id, pD[0]));
}

@isTest static void getgetPriceDetailsTest(){
    List<PriceDetail__c> pD = [Select Id, InvoiceCost__c, NetCost__c, RecordTypeId  FROM PriceDetail__c];
    System.assertNotEquals(null, AddPriceModalController.getPriceDetails(pD[0].Id));
}
}
```

im having an error in my test class on line 6, (Variable does not exist: PDRec)

here is the separate code of line 6:
   PriceDetail__c pD = PDRec.clone(false, true, false, false);

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You should create new records [not clone] in the `createData` method, like:

```
PriceDetail__c pD = new PriceDetail__c ();
```

as there is no `PDRec` variable holding a reference to a `PriceDetail__c` that can be cloned.